# NullPointerException in AsyncTask OnPostExecute with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, nullpointerexception

[When debugging I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzwY4.png)

After the line 'httpURLConnection.connect();' my code goes to the catch block and gives me this output:

[output catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ66k.png)
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBCrg.png)

I know there are several post on this topic but I don't seem to find a solution to it.  I don't understand why I am getting this error. I know that I most likely get a null object from my 'doInbackground()' method but I don't get why. Can someone help me understand this so I know how to fix it. Thank you !

My code :

```
    private  class PlaceRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url=new URL(params[0]);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                String line;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                if (jsonObject.has("next_page_token")) {
                    nextPageToken =jsonObject.getString("next_page_token");
                } else {
                    nextPageToken="";
                }
                return jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new JSONArray();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            requestCount++;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

                    String placeId = jsonObject.getString("place_id");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getDouble("lat"), location.getDouble("lng"));

                    GooglePlace googlePlace = new GooglePlace(name, placeId, latLng);
                    listPlaces.add(googlePlace);
                    MarkClusterItem markerClusterItem = new MarkClusterItem(latLng, name);
                    clusterManager.addItem(markerClusterItem);
                }
                clusterManager.cluster();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (requestCount < REQUEST_LIMIT && !nextPageToken.equals("")) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url=PLACES_REQUEST+"&pagetoken="+nextPageToken;
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> new PlaceRequest().execute(url), 2000);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the error:

```
2018-12-09 23:59:51.168 13210-13210/com.example.flow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.flow, PID: 13210
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.flow.displayClasses.WebscrapingScreens.GoogleMapsFragment$PlaceRequest.onPostExecute(GoogleMapsFragment.java:271)
        at com.example.flow.displayClasses.WebscrapingScreens.GoogleMapsFragment$PlaceRequest.onPostExecute(GoogleMapsFragment.java:218)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2018-12-09 23:59:51.204 1867-1881/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-09 23:59:51.329 1867-1935/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '7cc9433 com.example.flow/com.example.flow.displayClasses.LoginScreens.Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-12-09 23:59:51.329 1867-1935/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a9e800c com.example.flow/com.example.flow.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-12-09 23:59:52.005 1711-2262/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-09 23:59:52.059 1711-2050/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-09 23:59:54.394 1867-1983/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2018-12-09 23:59:57.468 5475-5549/? E/PlayCommon: [332] com.google.android.play.b.g.a(448): Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
2018-12-09 23:59:58.360 1867-1881/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-09 23:59:58.362 1867-1881/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-09 23:59:58.362 1867-1881/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.flow">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Eazy-Split"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:label"
        >

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyApsuynhkRf3A7p3fgKQp01EEF8l4tggXQ" />



        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:parentActivityName=".displayClasses.LoginScreens.Login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".displayClasses.LoginScreens.Login" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".displayClasses.LoginScreens.activity_signup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".displayClasses.LoginScreens.Login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Look above the crash stack trace for a trace that might be coming from the `e.printStackTrace()` in the  `catch` in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint at the catch but even then it crashes without getting information. @MikeM.

Comment: Well, `nextPageToken` is null. The `if-else` that sets it isn't being reached. Where exactly did you put the breakpoint?

Comment: I've placed it on the 'e.printStackTrace();' line.

Comment: when placing the breakpoint I noticed that the program stops running at 'httpURLConnection.connect();'. The message I get is 'The application is still running'. @MikeM.

Comment: And than I get the error nextPageToken=null. But my URL does contain my url with the api key.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying. If something's throwing in `doInBackground()`, then its stack trace will be printed in the `catch`. If you can't get stepping through with the debugger to work, just let it crash again, and look for the stack trace that will be before the crash's stack trace in your logs. I think the lines will be yellow, if you've still got the default settings.

Comment: @MikeM. I have posted what I get from debugging. And it seems that the connection won't work. But I don't get why..

Comment: @MikeM. the exception that I get is this one :Unable to resolve host: URL No address associated with hostname (link part 2)

Comment: Do you have the `INTERNET` permission listed in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I do, I just dubbel checked it myself.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the right spot? It must be outside of the `<application>` tags. Also, are you sure it's spelled exactly correctly?

Comment: It is placed autside the <application> and is spelled like this:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @MikeM. Added it to the post

Comment: Dunno. I checked it for any non-printing characters, and it seems OK. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You might try cleaning and rebuilding your project, and maybe Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyways. The only other thing that I found was that I shouldn't restrict my api key to android apps, but that isn't working either so.. If I find the solution i'll post it .

Comment: @MikeM. Done that as well without succes.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `new JSONArray()` object that is pretty much empty and it has not been populated with any changes that you applied to your instances inside `doInBackground`.

Inside your `doInBackground`, make sure you create a local `JSONArray` object, and pass to it all of your instances that you would like to retrieve in your `onPostExecute` method. In your case, if you have a string named `nextPageToken` which will be updated during `doInBackground`. Then, you will be able to retrieve in  `onPostExecute`.

**Do the following:**
In `doInBackground`: create a local instance: `JSONArray jsonArray;`
Write to your object whenever its necessary. **For example**:
`jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");`

Then at the end of your method `doInBackground`, return it:

```
return jsonArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Red M is right. You are returning an empty JSONArray.
You can create a JSONArray write to the object and return that JSONArray that have a value.
Example:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("your json value here");
```

then at the end of your code:

```
return jsonArray;
```